# npm install failing when it tries to download dependencies from bitbucket server

Tags: jenkins, npm-install

When i tried to run npm install command from freestyle job in jenkins It is failing with below error

```
npm ERR! command-line line 0: unsupported option "accept-new"
```

I found it is a bug -

```
[BUG] StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new causes install failure on OpenSSH <7.6 #31 as per https://github.com/npm/git/issues/31
```

As a workaround they have mentioned to add

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh" npm install
```

But after that i'm getting the below error

[image]

From detailed log

[image]

Could you please suggest how to fix this

freestyle job command as below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the error code - EMFILE - hitting ulimit conditions. After increased ulimit using ulimit -n  issue got fixed.